# Why does Java Collector.toList() require a wildcard type placeholder in its return type?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I've been doing some Java Streams manipulation, and of course it doesn't like my code and is refusing to provide useful error messages. (For reference, I have no problems whatsoever with C# and Linq, so I understand conceptually everything I'm trying to do.) So I started digging into adding the explicit generic types to every method in my code so I can find the source of the problem, as past experience tells me that this is a successful path forward.

While looking around I ran across something I don't understand. Consider the following code from the Java source (reformatted a little bit):

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList() {
    return new Collectors.CollectorImpl<>(
        (Supplier<List<T>>) ArrayList::new,
        List::add,
        (left, right) -> {
             left.addAll(right);
             return left;
        },
        Collectors.CH_ID
    );
}
```

Why does the `toList` method signature require a wildcard `?` in its return type? When I remove it, I get

> ```
> Wrong number of type arguments: 2; required: 3
> ```

and

> ```
> Incompatible types.
> Required: Collector<T, List<T>, >
> Found: CollectorImpl<java.lang.Object, List<T>, java.lang.Object>
> ```

When I change `?` to `Object`, I get (referring to these lines/methods in the above code):

> ```
> List::add – Cannot resolve method 'add'
> left.addAll – Cannot resolve method 'addAll(java.lang.Object)'
> ```

When I put the wildcard back and examine these two, they are:

> ```
> List – public abstract boolean add(T e)
> List – public abstract boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c)
> ```

Further fiddling around hasn't taught me anything more.

I understand that in one scenario such as the `? extends T`, the wildcard in Java can be translated over to C# as a new generic type argument with a `where TWildCard : T`. But what is going on with `toList` above, where the return type has a bare wildcard?

Comment: To clarify, you are asking about the wildcard in the return type `Collector<T, ?, List<T>>`, right?

Comment: @Radiodef Correct. Clarifying.

Comment: very good question, didn't think about it until now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Collectors [have three type parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html):

> `T` - the type of input elements to the reduction operation
>
> `A` - the mutable accumulation type of the reduction operation (often hidden as an implementation detail)
>
> `R` - the result type of the reduction operation

For some collectors, such as `toList`, the types of `A` and `R` are the same, because the result itself is used for accumulation.

The actual type of the collector returned from `toList` would be `Collector<T, List<T>, List<T>>`.

(An example of a collector which accumulates with a type which is different from its result is [`Collectors.joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--) which [uses a `StringBuilder`](http://web.archive.org/web/20171220020109/http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#Collectors.joining%28%29).)

The type argument to `A` is a wildcard most of the time because we don't generally care what it actually is. Its actual type is only used internally by the collector, and [we can capture it if we need to refer to it by a name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html):

```
// Example of using a collector.
// (No reason to actually write this code, of course.)
public static <T, R> collect(Stream<T> stream,
                             Collector<T, ?, R> c) {
    return captureAndCollect(stream, c);
}
private static <T, A, R> captureAndCollect(Stream<T> stream,
                                           Collector<T, A, R> c) {
    // Create a new A, whatever that is.
    A a = c.supplier().get();

    // Pass the A to the accumulator along with each element.
    stream.forEach(elem -> c.accumulator().accept(a, elem));

    // (We might use combiner() for e.g. parallel collection.)

    // Pass the A to the finisher, which turns it in to a result.
    return c.finisher().apply(a);
}
```

You can also see in the code for `toList` that it specifies [`Collectors.CH_ID`](http://web.archive.org/web/20171220020109/http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#Collectors.0CH_ID) as its characteristics, which specifies an identity finish. This means that its finisher does nothing except return whatever is passed to it.

---

(This section is referenced by my comment below.)

Here are a couple of alternative designs to carrying a type parameter for the accumulator. I think these illustrate why the actual design of the `Collector` class is good.

1. Just use `Object`, but we end up casting a lot.

   ```
   interface Collector<T, R> {
       Supplier<Object> supplier();
       BiConsumer<Object, T> accumulator();
       BiFunction<Object, Object, Object> combiner();
       Function<Object, R> finisher();
   }

   static <T> Collector<T, List<T>> toList() {
       return Collector.of(
           ArrayList::new,
           (obj, elem) -> ((List<T>) obj).add(elem),
           (a, b) -> {
               ((List<T>) a).addAll((List<T>) b);
               return a;
           },
           obj -> (List<T>) obj);
   }
   ```
2. Hide the accumulator as an implementation detail of the `Collector`, as the `Collector` itself does the accumulation internally. I think this could make sense, but it's less flexible and the combiner step becomes more complicated.

   ```
   interface Collector<T, R> {
       void accumulate(T elem);
       void combine(Collector<T, R> that);
       R finish();
   }

   static <T> Collector<T, List<T>> toList() {
       return new Collector<T, List<T>>() {
           private List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
           @Override
           public void accumulate(T elem) {
               list.add(elem);
           }
           @Override
           public void combine(Collector<T, List<T>> that) {
               // We could elide calling finish()
               // by using instanceof and casting.
               list.addAll(that.finish());
           }
           @Override
           public List<T> finish() {
               return new ArrayList<>(list);
           }
       };
   }
   ```

Comment: I’ve learned a lot so far. Thanks. The links were great. I’m going to study a bit before accepting the answer. I do wonder, when does the wildcard matter? Why have the accumulator type be part of the generic type parameters? How can the caller of a collector method care what the accumulator was as long as the output result is correct for the input?

Comment: There's a type parameter for the accumulator so that it can be captured and used by API code, like how I've used it in my example. Parallel stream collection, for example, would involve multiple threads, each with its own accumulator object, and a combiner step at the end. (I've also added a few more examples to my answer which I think help illustrate the point.) Why the actual design of `Collector` was chosen could be an interesting question for the designers.

Comment: Your new update did the trick! I see now that while there is no intrinsic problem with letting the accumulator be an implementation detail, by letting the Collector writer do so, the invariants around accumulators that Java says collectors are supposed to support may not be upheld. I still have thinking to do though. But why not just specify the accumulator type parameter as 'List<T>`? Why the need for the wildcard?

Comment: Besides just being shorter, I suppose it lets the implementation of a particular collector be changed in some ways without worrying about breaking code which relies on it. `Collectors.joining()` could be changed to use, say, a `StringJoiner` instead of a `StringBuilder`. I think that's probably why the official API does this. (It would be nice if Stuart Marks sees the Q&A, since he might have something to add. [I don't think an @ notification would work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/244864) to ask him directly.)

Comment: Interesting. To me this implies that there could have been two versions of a Collector. One for constructing such as a `CollectorDefinition<T, A,R>`, and one for using, `Collector<T, R>`, and the system takes one and gives you the other, so the invariants can be guaranteed. Exposing implementation details in a generic type parameter to code that not only doesn’t but *shouldn’t* care about such details seems like a code smell to me.

Comment: @Radiodef it would not, but he has a twitter account... I've tagged Stuart a few times, with partial success :)